# WinRT C# SVN Client

Tags: c#, windows, svn, windows-8

I try to connect SVN repo from Surface. And I realized that there are no apps for this. I want to write some one, but it's too complex to write my own SVN lib.
Are there some lib for WinRT ARM Architecture?

I found SharpSVN, but it doesn't support ARM WinRT.

Comment: Do you need app for your device or you want to develop ?

Comment: I want app, but I search throught Store and can't find. Therefore I decide to develop app.

Comment: ok, looking forward to it.

Comment: SharpSVN is open source. You could try porting it to WinRt.

Comment: SharpSVN is a wrapper on exe files, therefore it couldn't be running on WinRT (ARM).